# Changing the label, and test colour in a pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, pie-chart

I have used this code:

```
winner_percent=games_df.winner.value_counts(normalize=True)*100
winner_percent.plot(
    kind='pie',
    title='Proportion of piece colour effect on the game result',
    autopct="%.1f%%",
    colors=['white','black','grey'],
    explode=(0, 0.08, 0),
    figsize=(10,7),
    wedgeprops={"edgecolor":"k",'linewidth': 2, 'linestyle': 'solid', 'antialiased': True},
    textprops={'color':"b"}

)
plt.legend()
```

And the graph that I got is:

[image]

Would you please guide me for achieving:

- Changing the colour of the words White, Draw, and Black to **Black colour**.
- Change the percentage number inside the white portion of the pie chart to black colour text, and the other two sections (black and grey), the percentage number becomes white colour.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: First step, research what [`"b"` means](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html) in `'color':"b"`.

Comment: I know it means Blue, but I had to use it to show numbers on the black part!

Comment: Then you should have no problem resolving the first issue.

Comment: My main issue is how to change the colours of the numbers inside the pi-chart? I need to submit this by tomorrow..is it possible to guide me on that?

Comment: @BigBen it is not so simple unless you already know the answer ;) Vahid please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68865034/16343464)

Comment: @mozway - I guess what my comment was getting at is that changing `'color': "b"` to `'color': "k"` resolves issue 1, so if OP knows that already, issue 1 should not be included in the question.

Comment: @BigBen OK, I see, valid point ;)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot everything as black and change the two percentages manually as white:

```
winner_percent= pd.Series({'white': 49.9, 'black': 45.4, 'draw': 4.7}, name='Winner')
ax = winner_percent.plot(
        kind='pie',
        title='Proportion of piece colour effect on the game result',
        autopct="%.1f%%",
        colors=['white','black','grey'],
        explode=(0, 0.08, 0),
        figsize=(10,7),
        wedgeprops={"edgecolor":"k",'linewidth': 2, 'linestyle': 'solid', 'antialiased': True},
        textprops={'color':"k"}

    )

ax.texts[3].set_color('w')
ax.texts[5].set_color('w')
plt.legend()
```

output:

[image: matplotlib pie plot]

You can see the list of texts with:

```
>>> ax.texts
[Text(0.0034557017432522113, 1.099994571861817, 'white'),
 Text(0.001884928223592115, 0.5999970391973546, '49.9%'),
 Text(-0.17726600554646288, -1.1666090876028703, 'black'),
 Text(-0.10215329133185996, -0.6722832030253828, '45.4%'),
 Text(1.0880307327465517, -0.1618305428496183, 'draw'),
 Text(0.5934713087708463, -0.08827120519070088, '4.7%')]
```